# JPA to GET a joined entity returns a recursive fetch loop

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, recursion

I have a problem with a `@Get` method. I have an entity `ServcieChargeTier` which has a `@OneToMany` relationship with the entity `CalendarEntry`.

The problem is when I try and get a `ServiceChargeTier` from the server, the server returns a recursive loop of the ServiceChargeTier, which has `CalendarEntries`, which each has a ServiceChargeTier associated, which has the `CalendarEntries` and so on.

I would like to return the CalendarEntry's but not the associated ServiceChargeTier for each CalendarEntry.

ServiceChargeTier Mapping:

```
public class ServiceChargeTier {

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "associatedServiceChargeTier", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CalendarEntry> calendarEntries = new ArrayList<>();

...
}
```

CalendarEntry Mapping:

```
public class CalendarEntry {

...

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "service_charge_tier_id")
private ServiceChargeTier associatedServiceChargeTier;

...
}
```

When I make a request to get a ServiceChargeTier it returns a JSON like this:

```
[{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":{"id":40629,"calendarEntries":[{"id":40630,"associatedServiceChargeTier":
```

until it gives a stackOverFlow error.

Comment: You can exclude the field when serializing to JSON. If you use Jackson, check this : http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

Comment: which is nothing to do with the JPA API, and everything to do with JSON. They are totally different processes ...

Comment: @Thoomas thanks I will read through that.

Comment: @NeilStockton Yeah, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a bidirectional relation jackson will keep serializing each part of the relation when serializing the other, to solve it you can use @JsonIngore

```
public class CalendarEntry {

...
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "service_charge_tier_id")
private ServiceChargeTier associatedServiceChargeTier;

...
```

}

you could also create a DTO and convert your model as you want

Comment: Yep, that's what I wanted. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me lot !